# How do you make the ender portal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I make the ender portal? I've tried everything to make it but I can't.

Comment: there is no such thing as an 'ender portal'. there is a nether portal which you must construct, and a portal to the end which you cannot construct, you must find it in a stronghold. Which are you speaking of?

Comment: I think he is talking about Creative Mode.

Comment: Please, do some research (and show that you have done so) before posting a question.  The [Minecraft wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Minecraft_Wiki) is a great resource for answering a question like this. For instance, look at the [End Portal](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/End_Portal) article.

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying to create an End Portal in Creative Mode, you must surround the sides of an empty 3 by 3 square with End Portal Blocks, then fill all of them with Eye of Enders. You don't need the portal blocks at the corners, it just looks nicer. The last Eye of Ender placed must be facing IN the portal.

To add on to what kyr said, when you find the End portal in the stronghold, you still have to fill the portal blocks with Eye of Enders with the last one facing the inside of the portal.

[image: Example of an End Portal]

Comment: *"The blocks must be placed in specific orientation - placed from within the 3x3 area."* [source](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/End_portal)

Comment: What does"last on facing the inside of the portal" mean?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to "make" an End Portal in Survival Mode, find one in a Stronghold. You can find a Stronghold by using an Eye of Ender.

As for Creative Mode I go with Darakath's answer.